# Iphone Programming XML Parser NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, parsing, nsmutablearray

I am currently having a problem with parsing information from an XML into an NSMutableArray, i have pasted the code below which is for the parser this retrieves the document off the internet and constructs the array.  I am then trying to copy the items from the xml parser into an NSMutableArray for searching, but every time i try to copy the array it returns a struct error so i have removed the changes for now.

Here is the code for the parser and the current code for the viewdidload in the main view controller, if anyone can help i would really appreciate it.

```
#import "BlogRssParser.h"
#import "BlogRss.h"

@implementation BlogRssParser

@synthesize currentItem = _currentItem;
@synthesize currentItemValue = _currentItemValue;
@synthesize rssItems = _rssItems;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize retrieverQueue = _retrieverQueue;


- (id)init{
if(![super init]){
    return nil;
}
_rssItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
return self;
}

- (NSOperationQueue *)retrieverQueue {
if(nil == _retrieverQueue) {
    _retrieverQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    _retrieverQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
}
return _retrieverQueue;
}

- (void)startProcess{
SEL method = @selector(fetchAndParseRss);
[[self rssItems] removeAllObjects];
NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                 selector:method 
                                                                   object:nil];
[self.retrieverQueue addOperation:op];
[op release];
}

-(BOOL)fetchAndParseRss{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

//To suppress the leak in NSXMLParser
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxxx.co.uk/rssparser/Data.xml"];
BOOL success = NO;
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
[parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:YES];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
success = [parser parse];
[parser release];
[pool drain];
return success;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
if(nil != qualifiedName){
    elementName = qualifiedName;
}
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    self.currentItem = [[[BlogRss alloc]init]autorelease];
} else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"] || 
          [elementName isEqualToString:@"description"] ||
          [elementName isEqualToString:@"mediaUrl"] ||
          [elementName isEqualToString:@"link"] ||
          [elementName isEqualToString:@"guid"] ||
          [elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
    self.currentItemValue = [NSMutableString string];
} else {
    self.currentItemValue = nil;
}   
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if(nil != qName){
    elementName = qName;
}
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]){
    self.currentItem.title = self.currentItemValue;
}else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]){
    self.currentItem.description = self.currentItemValue;
}else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]){
    self.currentItem.linkUrl = self.currentItemValue;
}else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"mediaUrl"]){
    self.currentItem.mediaUrl = self.currentItemValue;
}else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"guid"]){
    self.currentItem.guidUrl = self.currentItemValue;
}else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]){
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    self.currentItem.pubDate = [formatter dateFromString:self.currentItemValue];
    [formatter release];
}else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]){
    [[self rssItems] addObject:self.currentItem];
}
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
if(nil != self.currentItemValue){
    [self.currentItemValue appendString:string];
}
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock{
//Not needed for now
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError{
if(parseError.code != NSXMLParserDelegateAbortedParseError) {
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [(id)[self delegate] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processHasErrors)
     withObject:nil
     waitUntilDone:NO];
}
}



- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
[(id)[self delegate] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processCompleted)
 withObject:nil
 waitUntilDone:NO];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}


-(void)dealloc{
self.currentItem = nil;
self.currentItemValue = nil;
self.delegate = nil;

[_rssItems release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

BlogRSSParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class BlogRss;
@protocol BlogRssParserDelegate;
@interface BlogRssParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>{
BlogRss * _currentItem;
NSMutableString * _currentItemValue;
NSMutableArray * _rssItems;
id<BlogRssParserDelegate> _delegate;
NSOperationQueue *_retrieverQueue;
}


@property(nonatomic, retain) BlogRss * currentItem;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString * currentItemValue;
@property(readonly) NSMutableArray * rssItems;

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<BlogRssParserDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSOperationQueue *retrieverQueue;

- (void)startProcess;


@end

@protocol BlogRssParserDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)processCompleted;
-(void)processHasErrors;

@end
```

ViewDidLoad

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self toolbarInit];
_rssParser = [[BlogRssParser alloc]init];
self.rssParser.delegate = self;
[[self rssParser]startProcess]; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "struct error"

Comment: expected struct nsarray * when passing argument 1 of initwitharray, this is when i was trying to populate an NSMutableArray with the contents of the _rssParser

Comment: can you post your code in your .h file too

Comment: added to the main body of the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You rssItems array is marked "readonly".

Change:

```
 @property(readonly) NSMutableArray * rssItems;
```

to

```
 @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * rssItems;
```

Comment: I've just tried this in the view controller trying to use the items from the _rssparser array using  displayitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:_rssParser];       but it returns the same warning mentioned above and then quits the app.  Do you think i should populate the array in the bloggrssparser.m or in the view controller as this is where the parser is run from, but i'm not sure how to get the items from the parser and put them into a mutble array.

Comment: I'm not seeing these statements in the code you've posted.  But it looks like you are trying to initialize a mutable array, but you are passing it an rssParser object.  Is _rssParser an instance of NSArray?  I suspect not.  Can you post that code too please>

Comment: if he's using ARC he should be using **@property(strong, nonatomic)**

Comment: I have just realised that the array that is holding all of the items from the xml is in blogrssparser.m and called rssitems and i am trying to copy items from an array that is not in the viewcontroller, would i better off synthesizing the array in the viewcontroller instead then would it be accessible to filter the items from for the search facility.

Comment: Yes, that would work.  OR, you could just reference the array in the parser, thus:  displayItems = _rssParser.rssItems;  Or, if you want to actually copy them (why?) you could do this:  NSMutableArray *displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:_rssParser.rssItems];

Comment: thats great thanks for the help the only problem i have now is when i am searching the app crashes and i get -[BlogRss rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b31e70 in the console.  Could you please elaborate as to what this error means as i've not much experience with adding search bars. thanks again for all your help

Comment: @user372256 - glad it's working for the most part.  Your next question should be another question.  I suggest you accept this answer and post a new question on SO since it's unrelated to the first one.

Comment: If this part is working, please accept this answer (that's how we get "paid" on SO).

Comment: worked great thanks ray the readonly settings was the main culprit.