# Searching NSMutableArray Crashing rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, xcode, parsing, exception, rss

I am having a problem with the search facility in my app and i have noticed that some postings on here are saying that there is a problem with the for loop of my code which you can see at the link below from a previous posting.

[Iphone Programming XML Parser NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914507/iphone-programming-xml-parser-nsmutablearray)

This is the comment from another person with the same problem and i would just like to know if the problem is the same for my project, "The objects in your search array are NSArray objects, this means that they do not respond to the selector rangeOfString: as that is a NSString method" and if so can i use a solution like this one.

```
for(NSArray *array in searchArray)
  {
// NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:0];
PatientInfoObject *obj = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *str = obj.id;
// to be sure
if( [str isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
{
   NSRange titleResultsRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveCompare];
   if( titleResultsRange.length != 0 )
   {
     [copyListOfItems addObject:str];
   }
}
else
{
    // this shouldn't have happened, log something to console
    NSLog(@"**Object in array is not of type NSString**");
 }
}
```

Here is the code for my UISearchBar, and as mentioned above the link at the beginning of the questions is to most of the relevant code if you need anything else i will post it.

Thanks
Brad

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchtext {
if ([searchtext length] == 0) {
    [self toggleToolBarButtons:NO];
    [[self rssParser]startProcess];
}
else {
    for (NSString * string in _rssParser.rssItems) {
        NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchtext options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
            [_rssParser.rssItems addObject:string];
        }
    }
}
[[self tableView]reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     for (NSString * string in _rssParser.rssItems) {
```

This code assumes that the the objects in the rssItems array are NSStrings.  From the other post, it appears that they are instances of BlogRss.

Maybe you need something like:

```
 NSString *matchingStringToAdd=nil;
 for ( BlogRss * blogRss in _rssParser.rssItems ) {
      NSString *string = blogRss.title;  // or whatever member you're seaching on
      NSRange titleResultsRange = [string rangeOfString:searchText
                                                options:NSCaseInsensitiveCompare];
      if ( titleResultsRange.location != NSNotFound ) {
           matchingStringToAdd = string;
           break;
      }
 }
 if ( matchingStringToAdd ) {
     [rssParser.rssItems addObject:matchingStringToAdd);
 }


-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
if ([searchText length] == 0) {
    //[self toggleToolBarButtons:NO];
    //[[self rssParser]startProcess];
    [displayitems removeAllObjects];
    [displayitems addObjectsFromArray:_rssParser.rssItems];
  } else {
    for ( BlogRss * blogRss in _rssParser.rssItems) {
        NSString *string = blogRss.title;  
        NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
            [displayitems addObject:blogRss];
        }
    }
}
[[self tableView]reloadData];
}
```

rssfunviewcontroller.h

```
@interface RssFunViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,BlogRssParserDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate> {
BlogRssParser * _rssParser;
UITableView * _tableView;
IBOutlet UISearchBar * searchbar;
RssFunAppDelegate * _appDelegate;
UIToolbar * _toolbar;
NSMutableArray * displayitems;
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"];
if(nil == cell){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"rssItemCell"]autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [[displayitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]title];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[displayitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]description];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
```

viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self toolbarInit];
_rssParser = [[BlogRssParser alloc]init];
self.rssParser.delegate = self;
[[self rssParser]startProcess]; 
displayitems = _rssParser.rssItems;
}
```

Comment: Thats great thanks Ray but all i get now is uncaught exception was mutated while being enumerated, the member i'm searching on is blogRSS.title.

Comment: Ok, I modified the code to not do the mod within the loop, but I have to ask why you're doing this.  You are finding a match in the array, and if found, you're adding another one to the same array.  So if your array contains (red, blue, green, yellow), and you find a match on blue, you will append blue, and then have (red, blue, green, yellow, blue).  Is that really what you want?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is follow a tutorial on the internet but it's not specifically written for the type of project i'm practicing with so i'm also trying to adjust it.  But what i'm trying to achieve is for a uisearchbar so i'm trying to iterate through array and filter out the matching searchText but as you can see i'm not doing so well. i've added my modified code to the question above.

Comment: Then you need to use a different NSMutableArray to hold the search matches.  I see you've done this already with "displayItems".

Comment: that's what i thought but i still get the iteration error that i mentioned above so i was not sure whether i was trying to iterate through the wrong array.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x4e48470> was mutated while being enumerated.(       This is the error that i keep getting and also the display shows a list of all of the description field of the array rather than the title that i have specified in the code above as NSString *string = blogRss.title;

Comment: Where is displayitems declared?  Also, make sure you clear it before adding any search hits to it.  (I assume that displayitems is the array that your tableview data source uses.)

Comment: As you can see from the viewdidload it starts the rss parser process and then copies the contents to the displayitems array from the rssParser.rssItems, then at the cellForRowAtIndexPath you can see it loads each of the content for the label and the subtitle from the displayitems array from indexPath.row]title and indexPath.row]description.  Then in the textDidChange method you can also see that i clear the tableview before reloading all the items from the displayitems database when the search text value is == 0.

Comment: But i have just noticed that if i put a space and then delete it, it removes all of the items from the list so that it is empty.  from the code i have written i thought it would reload all the content if there was nothing in the search bar.

Comment: `displayitems = _rssParser.rssItems;`
This is NOT copying the items from rssItems into display items.  This is basically pointing 2 variables at the same data.  What you need here instead is:
`[displayItems addObjectsFromArray:_rssParser.rssItems];`

Comment: I've just tried this and it seems when i try and populate the array in this manner it comes out with a blank tableview, will i need to add each object one at a time to the array from rssItems before trying to display on the tableview.